# Como indicar path y busque solo archivos con extensión .xml sin considerar nombre del archivo, solo la extensión

Tags: python

necesito indicar en mi  código la ruta de la carpeta donde se deja un archivo extensión .xml,
quiero independizarlo del nombre que cada usuario le ponga a dicho archivo y que solo busque por su extensión .xml

Hasta el momento solo pude indicar que tome el path donde esta mi codigo .py ahora me falta que busque el archivo que sea .xml sin considerar el  nombre que tenga

```
import os

# to get the location of the current python file
basedir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# to join it with the filename
file = os.path.join(basedir,'cualquier_nombre.xml')
```

desde ya muchas gracias, saludos

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Te conviene obtener todos los archivos xml en el path. Puedes utilizar varias funciones para lograrlo, entre ellas: [os.scandir](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/os.html#os.scandir), [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/os.html#os.listdir) y [glob.glob](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob). El como obtener un archivo xml a partir de estas funciones es algo que te toca a ti!

Comment: Sin embargo, te planteo un escenario. Que pasa si hay dos o más archivos xml en la misma carpeta? Cual es el que deberá abrir tu programa? el primero que encuentre?

Comment: @Dante  tienes razón! no lo había pensado, pero querría que tome el ultimo que se dejo en dicha carpeta considerando fecha/hora, gracias

Comment: Como te dijo Vichoco, esa es una pregunta diferente, te diría que publiques una nueva pregunta con eso. Pero me da miedo de que no sea bien recibida por no haber intentado algo. Politica que yo no apoyo mucho pero asi es la comunidad. En cuanto a tu nueva duda, hay un problema, segun la documentación de [os.stat_result](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/os.html#os.stat_result), objeto que se puede obtener con el modulo os, no existe una forma de saber cuando fue agregado el archivo en la carpeta. Puedes obtener (en Windows) su fecha de creación, modificación y ultimo acceso

Comment: No se si existe una manera de hacer eso, pero al menos yo no lo estoy encontrando.

Comment: Lo más simple sería hacer que el productor de esos archivos XML escriba la fecha o un orden en el nombre, y que el programa ocupe el nombre para decidir que agregar. Sin embargo, eso no escala en el tiempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta quieres encontrar el archivo con extensión .xml que se encuentre en un directorio.

Esto lo puedes lograr con os.listdir() y buscando entre la lista de archivos.
Claramente existen los casos de bordes si es que no existe archivo .xml o hay más de uno.

Sin embargo aquí te dejo la solución para listar todos los archivos con extensión xml:

```
[e for e in os.listdir(basedir) if ".xml" in e[-4:]]
```

Luego si quieres agarrar uno, basta con:

```
[e for e in os.listdir(basedir) if ".xml" in e[-4:]][0]
```

Comment: excelente @Vichoko muy  buena tu respuesta! ahora pensando en el caso que existiese mas de 1 archivo .xml en dicho path, se puede especificar  que tome el ultimo considerando fecha/hora? muchas gracias

Comment: Como que eso se escapa un poco del scope de la pregunta. De todas maneras si te complica mucho te motivo a usar el nombre de archivo fijo, asi es como lo hacen la mayoría de las aplicaciones. Hacer un escaneo para buscar archivos así puede llevar a resultados inesperados, y la verdad dejar un nombre fijo no es tan complicado. No se si vale el esfuerzo intentar hacerlo "smart. Es un consejo, pero estoy medio ciego igual porque no diste muchos detalles contextuales en tu pregunta.

Comment: perfecto @Vichoko necesitaba una guía/consejo/procedimiento de como hacerlo, muchas gracias.. saludos...